How to call without showing number using Twilio using C# API
I need to connect two customer via voice call, but I want to hide original phone number from each other. I thought to implement it using twilio.
when i run the console app i have an error the error showing is System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Twilio.TwilioClient' from assembly 'Twilio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.' 'Twilio.TwilioClient' from assembly 'Twilio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
